# How to customize interface of Rocket Chat

Tags: rocket.chat

I need to make some changes to the front-end of RocketChat. I've done a manual install on Ubuntu 16.04 and am new to the JS ecosystem. Simply editing files (such as `programs/server/packages/rocketchat_lib.js`) and redoing `npm install` doesn't seem to work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need some heavier changes like changing JS, menus and doing full customization you will have to build your own custom rocket.chat. It uses Meteor framework. You can find some guides [here](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides#developer-guides) and talk to people on the rocket.chat demo server channel [learn](https://demo.rocket.chat/channel/learn)

Answer (score 4):

To change your logo, background, and other settings related to UI, we need to log in as administrator and go to Administration area then Settings and Assets section and upload the relevant images there. And we can also make other UI  related settings from the layout section, which can include content, colors, fonts, and more.

Answer (score 2):

To customize the Rocket.Chat UI you can either modify the rocketchat-theme or rocketchat-ui packages directly, but if you’re keeping in sync with active development it would be easier to avoid conflicts by creating your own theme package.
You can add theme customisations to Rocket.Chat by just creating a Meteor package with your code, then adding it to the packages file.

Comment: If you're going to rip off the text from a page verbatim, you could at least source it! https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/ui-and-theming/themes/

Answer (score 1):

Well Rocket Chat allows us to change the logo. It also allows us to add custom CSS rules and change basic colors.

To change the colors and CSS go to administration and then under settings go to layout.

To change the logo go to administration and then under settings go to assets

Comment: What about adding some custom JS to the front-end or changing some text in the menu items? I'm wondering how full customization can be done.

Comment: You can use custom JS as well. just explore the settings menu

Answer (score 1):

Most* use of color in Rocket.Chat can be customised by changing color settings under Administration > Layout > Colors
Also you can use own CSS styles and so on in under Administration > Layout
Editing Rocket.chat files directly is bad way how to do it.

Some reference a HOW-TO are here https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/ui-and-theming

Comment: I'm actually looking for heavy customization such as add content of my own to screens, insert JavaScript here and there, etc. Can this be done?